# Python streamlit: When using element (here selectbox) within empty().container() doesn't update the variable value outside

Tags: python, streamlit

As an example to recreate my issue I use the following code:

```
import streamlit as st
from time import sleep
pg = st.empty()
with pg.container():
    start = st.button("start")
if start:
    pg.empty()
    sleep(0.02)
    with pg.container():
        num = st.selectbox("select num",[0,1,2,3,4])
        print(num)
    print(f'value of num outside is: {num}')
    if num:
        pg.empty()
        sleep(0.02)
        with pg.container():
            st.text(f"you selected: {num}")
```

Thank you in advance.

expected output is:
start button -> on clicked -> selectbox element (prints "0" and "value of num outside is 0" in cmd as it is the default selected option) -> on selecting any number except 0,example 2, container is emptied of the selectbox and replaced with a textbox displaying the selected number (prints "2" and "value of num outside is 2" in cmd)

what happens is:
start button -> on clicked -> selectbox element (prints "0" and "value of num outside is 0" in cmd as it is the default selected option) -> on selecting any number except 0,example 2, the selectbox is emptied from the container but no text box is displayed. And "2" or "value of num outside is 2" is not shows on cmd as well. Instead the start button is displayed again.

Comment: This is an expected streamlit behaviour. See [main concept and data flow](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/get-started/main-concepts). When you change selectbox, streamlit will rerun the code from top to bottom - hitting again the button and unfortunately the value of button is False again, so it cannot show the selectbox. However there is a workaround on this using session state.

Comment: Okay so the whole program reruns and if I have users with login option (for MySql), I have to save the login info as part of session state and it login every time again but fetch the login credentials from the session state and not from user again. Feels like it slows the program, but does the work. Thankyou.